# Convert from char array which representing double into hexadecimal value of the integer part

Tags: c, type-conversion

I want to find a way to convert from string representing floating point into hexadecimal value of the integer part in C language.

for an example:
lets say I got this string: 2356402635.0000000000

I am looking at 2356402635
I need that the output will be the hexadecimal value of the decimal number 2356402635 for an example: 0x8c73d9cb

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Read from the string one integer, and print the integer as hex.

Comment: [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) to get the integer part. Display it in any form you like.

Comment: Please elaborate, give more examples, especially some for which the word "exponent" makes any sense.

Comment: Also, "2356402635.0000000000" is not a floating point number. It is a string representation of a decimal number, with quite high precision (as expressed by number of zeroes). Do you need to read it in from text (keyboard or file or command line argument) as binary floating point number (`double` is better if `float` is not explicitly required)? Or is the whole "float" part redundant, as shown by your example?

Comment: @hyde You right i edit the question

Comment: There is no such thing as "hexadecimal value". Hexadecimal is presentation, the value is one in all presentations.

Answer (score 3):

String to integer conversion functions like `strtol` will convert until spotting a `.`. Unlike `strtod` which reads the whole number as if it was floating point.

So you can either use `strtol` to just grab the integral part or you can use `strtod` to read the whole number and then split the resulting `double` into integral/fractional parts with `modf`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("%"PRIx32"\n", (uint32_t)strtoul("2356402635.0000000000",0,10));
  
  double integral;
  (void) modf(strtod("2356402635.0000000000",0), &integral);
  printf("%"PRIx32"\n", (uint32_t)integral);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Worked with the strtoul function